# Run-time error '9' - Trying to refer to cells in existing sheet

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am super new to VBA and I am trying to automate the process of filling out a web form that is presently manually copy/pasted from an Excel sheet into a browser.

I was able to get my code to work and fill all the fields out with "Test" - but I would like to get it to fill out with values from cells in my workbook.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? :D

[image]

Comment: please do not post code as an image.  Please post the code as text and format it in code with three ` on the line before and three ` on the line after.

Comment: Do you get an error when you run your code/  If Yes what is the error message?

Comment: Either you don't have a workbook called "Macro_Test.xls", or that workbook does not have a worksheet called "Data".